# Optimised arraylist

Tags: c, optimization

I have this program that needs to do some comparisons of strings in an array. The first thought one would have is of course to just use `strcmp` to check whether two strings in the array are the same. Now consider the option that you just need to compare the pointers to the strings. This would involve some preparations to map each element that are literally the same to the same place in memory.

I've done all this, by preparing with `strcmp`, and now with `strstr` (which I believe is faster).
But because I need to check every string to map them to their first occurences, I get horribly long preparation-times. I should mention that this array is several MB large.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
[0x0: "I", 0x1: "am", 0x2: "done", 0x3: "here.", 0x4: "I", 0x5: "have", 0x6: "done", 0x7: "everything!"]

[0x10: 0x0, 0x11: 0x1, 0x12: 0x2, 0x13: 0x3, »0x14: 0x0«, 0x15: 0x5, »0x16: 0x2«, 0x17: 0x07]
```

So now to the question: Is there another way to do this kind of mapping faster than I am already doing?

Comment: Have you looked into using a hash table (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable)?

Comment: The question is updated.

Comment: Several comments/questions: Why would `strstr()` be faster? It does something rather different than `strcmp()`. Even after your edit, I still don't know what it is you're trying to accomplish - you might want to describe your end goal rather than how you're approaching it. Also code is usually better than describing code. Finally, what does any of this have to do with arraylist? (besides which, "arraylist" isn't a well-defined thing in C)

Comment: I believe strstr() would be faster because it is already doing at least one thing I want: Finding the first occurence or a substring. Also, strstr should also be well optimised, unlike any code I would write in a day. And finally, ArrayList is my name for a dynamic array, I guess this could have been left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just to see whether duplicates exist... you could run a `qsort()` on the array of strings and if your sort function finds a duplicate, you can bail early.  Or if you need to remove duplicates, then let the sorting complete and linearly iterate from the bottom of the list and pull them out as you find them (since all duplicates will be next to each other).

If the strings are relatively different, the `strcmp()` will realistically only need to check the first handful of characters before bailing on a failed match.  So it may not be as bad as you'd think.

Granted, the ease of doing this all depends on how the strings are really stored in memory.

UPDATE:

Ok, based on your update... Matt's suggestion of a hash table would probably work best:

- Iterate through your list one-by-one
- Hash the string
- Check to see if it exists in the table already
- If not, add it to the table and proceed
- If so, use the existing index from the table
- ... and then proceed to the next.

I'd imagine that should give you relatively decent performance, overall.